# dataSource on Websphere liberty

Tags: spring, datasource, jndi, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to setup a datasource on **websphere-liberty:springBoot2** docker image. I'm shared **a war file** and a **server.xml** file that contains a jdni definition

```
<dataSource id="oracle" jndiName="jdbc/oracle">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
    <properties ....... />
</dataSource>
```

The war file has the bean definition:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/oracle"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

But the next error stack appears:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: 
JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; 
nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: 
CWWKE0800W: An attempt was made to retrieve an initial context for [jdbc/oracle] but no JNDI feature is configured.
```

I'm shared both the server.xml and the ojdbc8.jar, to container. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the JNDI feature by adding `<feature>jndi-1.0</feature>` to the `<featureManager>` element of your server.xml  And you probably want to use the Oracle specific config element `properties.oracle` not the generic driver config element `properties`